# replacing two numbers by a single number which is in-between two in an given array?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

The problem is that we have an array A of lenght N and a random number X.

Choose any two numbers say a,b from array A and replace both of them by a single number say Y such that a<=y<=b.

After N-1 operations there should be only one number left in array A. Check whether can we get this number or not?

I think its recursive problem but I am unable to approach? 
please tell how to approach.

Comment: Is posting LIVE online competition problem allowed?

Comment: Maybe you need also the constrain that A precede B in the array?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then it's trivial to perform as long as X is between the minimum and maximum of the array (simply pick y=x each time). Maybe you should show an example.

Comment: What's `X` used for?

Comment: x is the number which needs to be checked whether it can be achieved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say array is a1, a2,.., an in sorted order. So minimum is a1 and max is an;

```
you may choose a1,a2 and replace with a1. 
Then after choose a1, a3(as a2 is gone now) and replace by a1.
.
Similarly you may choose a1, an-1 {a2 to an-2 is gone now} and replace by a1.

Now you are left with 2 number a1 and an. So a1<=x<=an, ans is yes otherwise two.
```

This is greedy approach so it requires a proof. That i am leaving on you.

Just a sidenote: recusion and iteration has same mathematical power. It just that they have different visualization.